# Add thousands separator to "xxxx views" tooltip in question list

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, views, information-display

When hovering over the number of views in a question list, the exact number of views is shown without thousands separator, e.g.

> 214935 views

[image]

Can this be added, just like already done on the question statistics under the title on the Q&A page:

[image]

Comment: How subtle a bug....

Comment: Should it be a comma (one standard among others (period or space)), or no separator at all?

Comment: Since Stack Exchange is an English site, I'd expect a comma.